# Issue with cfquery text encoding

Tags: sql, sql-server, utf-8, coldfusion, iso-8859-1

I have an encoding problem with the cfquery tag.

This is my code:

```
<cfquery name="query" datasource="example">
    SELECT *
    FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE
    WHERE EXAMPLE_COLUMN = 'WORD WITH ACCENT É'
</cfquery>
```

When doing a cfdump on the query variable, the generated sql by  the cfquery tag changes the text to 'WORD WITH ACCENT Ã‰' but I need it to be É because the value in the table is set that way. Is there any way to change the encoding of the cfquery tag?

I tried changing the encoding of the page with the cfcontent tag to no avail. I also tried to use SetLocale() without much result either.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe the `cfdump` tag does some translation when outputting data. Try using `cfoutput` on that specific column and see if you get the proper results.

Comment: that's the problem. I don't get any results. When I run the exact same query in SQL Server Management Studio, it returns rows, but not in coldfusion :(

Comment: Is `'WORD WITH ACCENT É'` *actually* in your source code or is it rather a dynamic value, e.g. from a FORM or URL scope?

Comment: Did you try it with cfquery parameter?

Comment: Tomalak, it is in the source code.
Dan, yes I did try, and it didn't work.
But i found a solution now so it's good.
Thanks guys.

Comment: Then your [cfprocessingdirective](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21046851/104223) code is the correct solution. Good job :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
<cfprocessingdirective pageEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

Added this at the top of the page and it works like a charm.

Comment: For reasons of consistency it might be better to save the CFML source file in the encoding the server expects. (See CF Administrator -> "Server Settings" -> "Settings Summary" -> "Java File Encoding".)

Answer (score 0):

This is a formatted comment.

When I ran

```
<cfquery name="x" datasource="dw">
select count(*) records
from event
where event_code = 'WORD WITH ACCENT É'
</cfquery>
<cfdump var="#x#" metainfo="yes">
```

The metainfo sql showed:

select count(*) records from event where event_code = 'WORD WITH ACCENT É'

I am using ColdFusion 9.1 and the query was against a redbrick database.  I got similar results with oracle and sql server databases

Comment: What is the encoding of your source file?

Comment: The server setting is "Java File Encoding  Cp1252".  The only code on the .cfm page was as shown in the question.  In fact, I did not even have any html tags of any sort.